# How to fix the drum part's staff in the correct form in Sibelius?

Tags: midi, drums, sibelius

I wrote the drum part in DAW, exported the midi and imported it to Sibelius. It recognized this track in this form:

[image]

How can I quickly transform it into the correct form and remove these polyphony?

Such as this:

[image]

It is reproduced correctly, i.e. all sounds (bass drum, cymbals) are in the correct positions

Comment: If some of those are bass drum parts and some of those are not (i.e. some of them are played with your feet and some of them are played with your hands), I personally highly recommend **not removing the polyphony**. However, I have seen some metal drumming sheet music for sale with the polyphony removed (makes the drum part harder to read, IMO).

Comment: @Dekkadeci I have more of a question about the form of notes, not polyphony, but thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you just re-write the drum stave in Sibelius, using the imported stave as a guide.   There's just so MUCH to fix between an import from DAW import and a readable drum part that any automatic solution would probably be more trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suspect it is really easier to write everything with hands. But I have a lot of score pages. I think there may still be a function that can change the note symbol at a certain pitch, for example, to make all the notes of the hi-hat with crosshairs or something like that